# Why I can run my application in eclipse, but I can't do it in terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

everybody.

I have a java project. I can run it in eclipse. and I can find its .class file. But how do I run the .class file? I don't setup the javapath or classpath at all.

I downloaded java(I forgot jdk or jre) on the internat. It's an .exe file. I double clicked it, and it is installed.

When I type "java", system can find it. But when I type javac, system can't find it. when I type java Test1, the system says "Error: Could not find or load main class Server".
What is the problem？

I think I've already installed java. But I don't know how to find it.

Maybe I did't install jdk. But I think the .class file will still work without it.

Comment: Check this Oracle Java tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html

Comment: Please improve your question -- show your attempts to run it on the terminal. Let us know if you can run a very simple program in the same package, on the terminal. Show your code if not too large or the pertinent code if it is.

Comment: Perfectly explained here: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/04/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-helloworld-java.html

Comment: The code is okey, I think. Because it works in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Since javac does not work, you either have the jre installed, rather than the jdk, or javac's folder has not been added to your path.  To run from the command line, you need to navigate to the root of the project, and run the command from there, rather than the directory in which the actual file resides.

Comment: But I am sure I install java. Because I double the .exe file. And It is in "appwiz.cpl".

Comment: type javac, and see what it says.  If javac is not installed, you will need to install the jdk